# Sqlite group by distinct count

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have table of customers operations:

```
date, client_id, gender
1     1          M
1     1          M
1     2          M
1     2          M
1     3          F
2     1          M
2     1          M
2     1          M
2     2          M
2     2          M
2     3          F
2     3          F
2     4          F
2     5          M
2     5          M
etc
```

Desired output is:

```
date, amount of males, (also need amount of females)
1     2                1 
2     3                2
```

I need to group it by date, so i did it, then my goal is to find amount of each gender in each grouped group.
so i tried to do this to count amount of males:

```
sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else NULL end) as 'M%'
```

but its counted clients id 1 and 2 two times each, but i need to count it distinct.
On example above i expect this to return 2 because 2 male. But it return 4 because distinct construction doesnt work.
I tried this but it doesnt work and count '1' in result:

```
sum(distinct case when gender = 'M' then 1 else NULL end) as 'M%'
```

Comment: Do you only need `date` and a `gender` count, ignoring the `client_id`?

Comment: I used `group by date` so i need to count amount of males in each group. But only "unique" values, so in example table it should be 2 because there are 2 client_id with male gende. Not 4

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: If you have found a solution that differs from the answers already posted, please post it as a new answer. If one of the answers below serves as a solution, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark next to its score. Do not edit your question to include a solution; that is not what questions are for.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
select date,
    count(distinct case when gender = 'M' then client_id end) as count_m,
    count(distinct case when gender = 'F' then client_id end) as count_f
from t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to count from the distinct rows of the table.
Also, use SQLite's feature to treat boolean expressions as `1` for `true` and `0` for `false` so you can sum them instead of using `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT date,
       SUM(gender = 'M') [amount of males],
       SUM(gender = 'F') [amount of females]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date, client_id, gender FROM tablename)
GROUP BY date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c808f502c4f4dfcb51c53b216ae51561).